# GeoServer port does not change

Tags: geoserver, windows, web-service, jetty

I have GeoServer 2.22.0 installed on a Windows machine as a service.

I want to install another GeoServer on another port but the GeoServer installer tells me that I already have a GeoServer and should unistall it first.

I decided to change the port from the default 8080 to something else to be able to install the new instance.

However, there is no mention of "port" in my jetty.xml file except this one:

```
      <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
```

I checked the "C:\Program Files\GeoServer\bin\startup.bat", the only mention of "port" is this part:

```
:run
  cd "%GEOSERVER_HOME%"
  echo Please wait while loading GeoServer...
  echo.
  "%RUN_JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="%GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR%" -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar
  cd bin
goto end
```

Finally I saw that in the service "Path to Executable" section,

[image]

this command is written:

```
"C:\Program Files\GeoServer\wrapper\GeoServer.exe" -ini "C:\Program Files\GeoServer\wrapper\jsl64.ini"
```

I have checked the file jsl64.ini and this is its content:

```
;GeoServer Java Service Launcher (JSL) configuration

[service]
appname=GeoServer
servicename=GeoServer
displayname=GeoServer 2.22.0
servicedescription=GeoServer is an open source software server written in Java that allows users to share and edit geospatial data.
account=NT Authority\NetworkService

;Console handling
useconsolehandler=true
stopclass=java/lang/System
stopmethod=exit
stopsignature=(I)V

;Logging
logtimestamp="%%Y-%%m-%%d"
systemout=%GEOSERVER_HOME%\logs\geoserver.log
systemoutappend=yes
systemerr=%GEOSERVER_HOME%\logs\geoserver.log
systemerrappend=yes

;Failure handling
failureactions_resetperiod=300000
failureactions_actions=4
action0_type=1
action0_delay=10000
action1_type=1
action1_delay=10000
action2_type=1
action2_delay=10000
action3_type=0
action3_delay=10000

[java]
jrepath=%JAVA_HOME%
jvmsearch=path
wrkdir=%GEOSERVER_HOME%
cmdline=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djetty.http.port=8080 -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -Xbootclasspath/a:./webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/marlin-0.9.3.jar -Dsun.java2d.renderer=org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine -jar start.jar
```

I have changed "-Djetty.http.port=8080 " to 8090 but still the service is running on 8080!!
I have restarted the service and even the server a couple of times.

Now, I have two questions:

1. How I can change the port of this GeoServer?
2. What does it mean:-DSTOP.PORT  what does it do?

Comment: STOP.PORT is documented in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Secure_Termination.